Why ARM ELF does not running on Bluestacks rooted emulator?
I have ELF Executable file (arm-fm-22k):
OnePlus5:/storage # ls
arm-fm-22k emulated self

And when I going to run, every time I see this message:
OnePlus5:/storage # ./arm-fm-22k
sh: ./arm-fm-22k: not executable: 32-bit ELF file
1|OnePlus5:/storage # 

It seems kernel shows that, because I running 32-bit ELF on 64-bit Android. But NO! Right now I'm in 32-bit Nougat.
Why Android Bluestacks kernel does not want to run my ELF file?

Probably, the problem is about incompatible architectures (x86/ARM). With file arm-fm-22k you could check architecture of your executable. With uname -a you could check architecture of your OS.

What is the output from file arm-fm-22k?

Now I have run this in my Android phone, and it wrote: "Segmentation fault".
